# Django for loop issue

Tags: html, django, for-loop

I think this is something simple but I cannot find the error at all. 
The code inside the for loop is not executing. When I look up the database and the admin site the content displays fine but trying to display on the HTML is not working:

Views

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.utils import timezone
    from .models import Post
    def post_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
        return render(request, "blog/bloglist.html", {'posts': posts})
```

Urls:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^blog/$', views.post_list),

    ]
```

Base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Base</h1>

            {% block content %}

            {% endblock  %}

 </body>
 </html>
```

bloglist.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Blog </h1>
    {% for post in posts %}


            <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>



    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and just to be sure the model is included as well
Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I know its pretty simple but I just cannot find the error. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is shown in the page?

Comment: Base Blog each on seperate lines which is why i think the error is in either the models or the views not creating the 'post

Comment: Try `Post.objects.all()` for list of all blog posts. Also add `{{ posts }}` in template or `print(posts)` in `views.py` to check if data is actually coming. Check source code of page to see if there are any empty <h3></h3> tags.

Comment: @ciarandarcy I think there is a problem at `render()` in your views. Check if you have namespaced your templates in respective apps